# Best way to get URL from Nodejs results while only knowing link text

Tags: node.js, regex, cheerio

After getting html results from a nodejs GET, what's the best way to retrieve the URL of a link when I only know the link text. Can I use cheerio? regex? jQuery?

for example, how would I retrieve the URL for "second website"

```
<a href='www.website1.com'>first website</a>
<a href='www.website2.com'>second website</a>
<a href='www.website3.com'>third website</a>
```

Comment: Asking for the best way to do something often makes it primarily opinion based. So, it really depends on your requirements and the context. 

I, personally would avoid regexes. Because HTML is not a regular language, thus it shouldn't/cannot be parsed with regular expressions. Other options should work fine.

Comment: @fardjad , how would I do it with cheerio? I'm not sure how to specify link text element. for example `$('second website').attr('href')` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a:contains("second website")').attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to use a selector rather than run through each hyperlink, but here's what worked for me:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(body);
links = $('a'); //get all hyperlinks
  $(links).each(function(i, link){
      var currentlink = $(link).text()
      if(currentlink.includes('second')){
            console.log($(link).text() + ':\n  ' + $(link).attr('href'));
      }
  });
```